# How do I prove this limit doesn't exist without L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to prove that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0+}\arccos\left(\ln(1-2x)^\frac{1}{4x}\right)
$$
does not exist. I have already found out that $f(0)$ is $\pi/2$, and that the function only exists in Quadrant 2. Since the function only exists in Quadrant 2, the limit approaching $0$ from the right does not exist. I'm having trouble writing this out in words, and proving it using the limit. Is it as simple as just saying that, as ${x \to 0+}$, $\ln(1-2x)$ approaches $\ln(1)$, and the exponent $\frac{1}{4x}$ approaches $\frac{1}{0}$, meaning that the function is undefined because it gives us $0^\frac{1}{0}$?

Comment: Are you sure this limit doesn't exist as $x \to 0^+$?  (I'm assuming that's what's intended, rather than $h \to 0^+$.)  Maybe I'm not reading what you mean, correctly.

Comment: If you're talking about $\arccos x$, that exists in both Quadrants 1 and 2.

Comment: It should be $x\rightarrow 0^+$. How about considering two sequences of points converging to $0$ from the right and showing that two (distinct) limits exist?

Comment: Well, then I've done something wrong and I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: it seems so that you are right

Comment: Encountering something along the lines of $0^{1/0}$ doesn't "break" this expression. Consider $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{1/x}$ which has that same $0^{1/0}$ format; this limit still exists and is $0$. (This doesn't mean that your limit is $0$, or even that your limit exists -- just that having $0^{1/0}$ is not an obstruction.)

Comment: @Alpha You are making mistake in computing $\lim_{x \to 0} (1-2x)^{\frac{1}{4x}} =(exp)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Are we applying $\arccos$ to $\ln [(1-2x)^{1/4x}]?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \, \arccos(\log (1-2 x))^{1/4x}$$
Cannot exist for another reason

The domain of the function must guarantee the existence of logarithm and arccos

Therefore must be
$$0<(\log (1-2 x))^{1/4x}\leq 1$$
taking logarithm of both sides
$$\frac{1}{4x}\log(\log(1-2x))\leq 0$$
$$x\leq \frac{1-e}{2}\approx-0.86$$
so the domain of this function is $\left(-\infty,\;\dfrac{1-e}{2}\right]$

no limit (right or left) can be computed for $x\to 0$

Hope this helps

Comment: The function uses lnx, not logx. Does this make a difference?

Comment: There is no difference: both are "natural" logarithm in base $e$

Comment: Where did $x\to 0^-$ come from?

Comment: So if $x\to 0^+,$ there's an easier reason why the domain is a problem. $\ln (1-2x) < 0,$ so raising that to arbitrary positive powers is not defined.